# Android Studio split APK over Density

Tags: android, gradle, split, apk

```
splits {

        // Configures multiple APKs based on screen density.
        density {
            // Configures multiple APKs based on screen density.
            enable true

            reset()
            // Specifies a list of screen densities Gradle should create multiple APKs for.
            include 'ldpi', 'mdpi', 'hdpi', 'xhdpi', 'xxhdpi', 'xxxhdpi'
            // Specifies a list of compatible screen size settings for the manifest.
            //compatibleScreens 'small', 'normal', 'large', 'xlarge'
        }
        // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
        abi {
            // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
            enable false
            // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
            // want APKs for x86, armeabi-v7a, and mips.
            // Resets the list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for to none.
            reset()
            // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
            include 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
            // Specifies that we do want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
            universalApk true //generate an additional APK that contains all the ABIs

            //'armeabi' - Not surported by Realm since v2.0.0
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to split my APKs by Desity in order to reduce APK size, using the above Gradle it splits the APKs into densities but the drawable resources for each APK are identical.

Should the result of this not be that the xhdpi APK only contains only drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi-v17, drawable-xhdpi-v4 and mipmap-xhdpi-v4?

Comment: Do you have all your drawables as xxxhdpi versions? This isn't necessary. Look at the first hint at https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support This can reduce your APK Size dramatically. Also, you can think about letting the ldpi drawables out. They can be sized down from mdpi.

Comment: No we only have xml drawables and we can't vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true because of other dependencies

Answer (score -2):

Example of density apk split in gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
  compileSdkVersion 19
  buildToolsVersion = rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
  defaultConfig {
    versionCode 12
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 20
    buildConfigField "String", "FOO", "\"bar\""
  }
  splits {
    density {
      enable true
      exclude "ldpi", "tvdpi", "xxxhdpi", "400dpi", "560dpi"
      compatibleScreens 'small', 'normal', 'large', 'xlarge'
    }
  }
}
// map for the version code
ext.versionCodes = [all:1, mdpi:2, hdpi:3, xhdpi:4, xxhdpi:5]
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
  // assign different version code for each output
  variant.outputs.each { output ->
    def key = output.getFilter(OutputFile.DENSITY) == null ? "all" : output.getFilter(OutputFile.DENSITY)
    output.versionCodeOverride = project.ext.versionCodes.get(key) * 100 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
  }
}
```